# C#: How set "on row command" event handler of a gridview dynamically?

Tags: c#, gridview, event-handling

Can I change "on row command" event handler of a gridview dynamically from code and in run time?
I use C#

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your handlers somewhere in your code where you want changed (perhaps in a click event handler).  If necessary, remove your old handler beforehand.

```
gridView.RowCommand -= MyOldRowCommandHandler;
gridView.RowCommand += MyNewRowCommandHandler;
```